# MapReduce development inside Eclipse on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, hadoop

I'm running Hadoop cluster HDP-2.2.4.2-2.
I would like to develop MapReduce jobs on Windows machine. I've configured Eclipse with Hadoop plugin and HDFS browser inside Eclipse works fine. However, after start basic WordCount job on cluster it ends up with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:730)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:488)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:528)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:506)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:298)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:437)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
at wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:102)
```

I also try to debug and variables before error occurred seems following:

http://postimg.org/image/73ubc44ev/

It seems like file system error - eclipse try to change permission on windows file system file using linux chmod... But I'm not sure if it is a reason for NullPointerException. There are also som null variables which could cause this issue - dir and environment.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you try the setup through Cygwin ([link](http://bigdata-guide.blogspot.com/2014/01/hadoop-installation-on-windows-with.html))?

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't help